# Ransack + FlagShihTzu + Active Admin don't play well together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ransack

I'm using the brilliant gem [flag_shih_tzu](https://github.com/pboling/flag_shih_tzu) to create bitwise boolean flags on a single integer column without requiring a separate DB column for each flag.  I have loved this gem for many years now, and it's quite excellent at interplaying with ActiveRecord attributes in all the ways you would normally expect.

However, it does not play well with Ransack and Active Admin out of the box.  Active Admin requires me to add permitted params for each flag:

```
  permit_params do
   :identity_verified
  end
```

for the :identity_verified "flag" attribute to even show up in filters or index columns, which is fine; I don't mind that.  But the real problem I'm having is when I try to use the :identity_verified flag as a filter (it's boolean, of course), Active Admin shows the normal select option for it with Any/Yes/No, but when I first submitted the filter query, I got an exception: `undefined method identity_verified_eq for Ransack::Search`.

Ok, so I did some research and figured out that I need to add a `ransacker` for :identity_verified.  Did that, and I don't get the exception anymore, but the ransacker doesn't appear to do anything at all.  In fact, I intentionally put a syntax error in the block to cause an exception, but Active Admin just returns all the Users, regardless of whether they're :identity_verified or not.  That code inside the `ransacker` block doesn't seem to even get executed.  Can anyone help me figure out how to create a proper Ransack definition for :identity_verified?

Here's the code:

User Model :

```
  #  ===============
  #  = FlagShihTzu =
  #  ===============

  has_flags 1  => :guest,             
            2  => :prospect,         
            3  => :phone_verified,   
            4  => :identity_verified,


  #  ==============
  #  = Ransackers =
  #  ==============

  # this avoids the identity_verified_eq missing method exception, but 
  # doesn't appear to do anything else
  ransacker :identity_verified, args: [:ransacker_args] do |args|
    asdf # <-- should cause an exception
    Arel.sql(identity_verified_condition)
  end
```

Active Admin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params do
    :identity_verified
  end

  # ...

  filter :identity_verified, as: :boolean

  # ...

end
```

The Identity Verified filter shows up as a boolean select in Active Admin, like I expect, but when I submit the filter, (as I metioned above), I get all the Users back, and the ransacker block doesn't even seem to get executed.  I've read the [Ransack examples](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers). I've dug into the code of all four gems (including Formtastic), and I still can't sort it out.

Here's the POST URL from Active Admin on query submit:

```
http://example.com/admin/users?q%5Bidentity_verified%5D=true&commit=Filter&order=id_desc
```

Here's the Rails log to confirm the :identity_verified param is getting passed:

```
Processing by Admin::UsersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"identity_verified"=>"true"}, "commit"=>"Filter", "order"=>"id_desc"}
```

Again, the inside of the ransacker block doesn't seem to get executed.  I need to understand why, and if it ever does, how to write the proper Arel statement so I can filter on this flag.

Help?

Comment: Your query params is `identity_verified ` and not `identity_verified _eq`, why?

Comment: @omarvelous, because that's the way Ransack works.  The parameter is `identity_verified`, but the method that needs to exist on the model is `:identity_verified_eq`.  For normal ActiveRecord columns, Ransack creates these methods automatically.  For non-AR attributes, you need to define the `:identity_verified_eq` method your self using a custom `ransacker`.  That is what I need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resurrecting this question as it is the first result on G* here searching for "flag shih tzu activeadmin". Plus it seems OP's solution is not ideal in that it loads & instantiates AR objects for all records fulfilling the flag condition in this part:

```
results = object_class.send("#{flag}")
results = results.map(&:id)
```

So here's my current solution for others:

```
# config/initializers/ransack.rb
Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.add_predicate 'flag_equals',
    arel_predicate: 'eq',
    formatter: proc { |v| (v.downcase == 'true') ? 1 : 0 },
    validator: proc { |v| v.present? },
    type: :string
end

# app/concerns/has_flags.rb
module HasFlags
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included { include FlagShihTzu }

  class_methods do
    def flag_ransacker(flag_name, flag_col: 'flags')
      ransacker(flag_name) do |parent|
        Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('DIV',
          Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('&', parent.table[flag_col], flag_mapping[flag_col][flag_name]),
          flag_mapping[flag_col][flag_name])
      end
    end
  end
end

# app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HasFlags

  has_flags 1 => :bar, 2 => :baz
  flag_ransacker :bar
end

# app/admin/foos.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Foo do 
  filter :bar_flag_equals, as: :boolean, label: 'Bar'
end
```

Comment: Nice solution, Malte.  Much more performant.  Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally figured out the answer after luckily stumbling on to this post [ActiveAdmin Filters with Ransack](http://cavewall.jaguardesignstudio.com/2014/05/01/activeadmin-filters-with-ransack/).  The gist of it is properly defining the Active Admin filter using the DSL and more importantly, the appropriate ransacker in the model for the FlagShihTzu flag you want to filter on.

Here's a working example:

models/user.rb:

```
class User
  include FlagShihTzu

  # define the flag
  has_flags 1 => :identity_verified

  # convenience method to define the necessary ransacker for a flag

  def self.flag_ransacker(flag)
    ransacker flag.to_sym,
    formatter: proc { |true_false|
      if true_false == "true"
        results = object_class.send("#{flag}")
      else
        results = object_class.send("not_#{flag}")
      end
      results = results.map(&:id)
      results = results.present? ? results : nil
    }, splat_params: true do |parent|
    parent.table[:id]
  end

end
```

admin/user.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  # A method used like a standard ActiveAdmin::Resource `filter` DSL call, but for FlagShizTzu flags
  # A corresponding `flag_ransacker` call must be made on the model, which must include
  # the FlagShizTzuRansack module defined in app/concerns/models/flag_shih_tzu_ransack.rb
  def flag_filter(flag)
    @resource.flag_ransacker flag.to_sym # call the ransacker builder on the model
    flag = flag.to_s
    filter_name = "#{flag}_in" # we use the 'in' predicate to allow multiple results
    filter filter_name.to_sym,
      :as => :select,
      :label => flag.gsub(/[\s_]+/, ' ').titleize,
      :collection => %w[true false]
  end

  flag_filter :identity_verified

end
```

And voila, a working sidebar filter for flag-shih-tzu flags.  The key was adding the `in` predicate at the end of the flag name in the filter declarion, instead of excluding it, which defaults to the `eq` Ransack predicate.  Defining the ransacker itself took trial and error using pry and the debugger, but was based largely on the aforementioned post.

Ultimately, I ended up pulling out the inline methods in the two files into modules that I include in the necessary models and AA resource definitions that need them.

app/concerns/models/flag_shih_tzu_ransack.rb:

```
# Used to define Ransackers for ActiveAdmin FlagShizTzu filters
# See app/admin/support/flag_shih_tzu.rb
module FlagShihTzuRansack
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    # +flags are one or more FlagShihTzu flags that need to have ransackers defined for
    # ActiveAdmin filtering
    def flag_ransacker(*flags)
      object_class = self
      flags.each do |flag|
        flag = flag.to_s
        ransacker flag.to_sym,
          formatter: proc { |true_false|
            if true_false == "true"
              results = object_class.send("#{flag}")
            else
              results = object_class.send("not_#{flag}")
            end
            results = results.map(&:id)
            results = results.present? ? results : nil
          }, splat_params: true do |parent|
          parent.table[:id]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

app/admin/support/flag_shih_tzu.rb:

```
# Convenience extension to filter on FlagShizTzu flags in the AA side_bar
module Kandidly
  module ActiveAdmin
    module DSL

      # used like a standard ActiveAdmin::Resource `filter` DSL call, but for FlagShizTzu flags
      # A corresponding `flag_ransacker` call must be made on the model, which must include
      # the FlagShizTzuRansack module defined in app/concerns/models/flag_shih_tzu_ransack.rb
      def flag_filter(flag)
        @resource.flag_ransacker flag.to_sym # call the ransacker builder on the model
        flag = flag.to_s
        filter_name = "#{flag}_in" # we use the 'in' predicate to allow multiple results
        filter filter_name.to_sym,
          :as => :select,
          :label => flag.gsub(/[\s_]+/, ' ').titleize,
          :collection => %w[true false]
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL.send :include, Kandidly::ActiveAdmin::DSL
```

Then more cleanly, in the model:

```
class User
  include FlagShihTzu
  include FlagShihTzuRansack

  # define the flag
  has_flags 1 => :identity_verified
```

end

and in the resource definition:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  flag_filter :identity_verified

end
```

There are probably more elegant implementations of the methods, but having a working solution, I'm moving on.  Hope this helps whoever up-voted this question.  Ransack documentation leaves a bit to be desired.  Thanks to Russ for his post on Jaguar Design Studio, and to the commenters on https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/36, who helped me better understand how Ransack works. In the end I had to dig into the gems to get my final solution, but I would not have known where to start without their contributions.